# How can I view javadocs without adding them to the package through their generation?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I want to see some javadocs in Eclipse 3.7. If I use "Generate javadocs", the javadocs are added to my project in the 'docs' folder. I would prefer to only view the javadocs, without them being permanently added to my project. Is there a more elegant way to do this than generating and deleting them?

Comment: If you hover (or press F2) over an object/method, it will find the Javadoc and display it for you. Why do you want to generate the whole javadoc package if you don't want to keep it?

Answer (score 0):

You can view Java Docs using the above method as mentioned in comment. If you not find any docs attached with it, then you can attach source. for that you can point the source folder of your java installation directory (i.e src.zip) so that it will be taken care by eclipse to view the docs irrespective of your project.
Hope this helps.